# How to keep selection on copy with VSCodeVim

Tags: vscodevim

When I select code in visual mode or with the mouse and then press Cmd+C, I lose the selection.

This does not happen when VSCodeVim is turned off.

How do I have to configure VSCodeVim to keep the selection on pressing Cmd+C?

I already tried the following options to no avail:

```
"vim.useSystemClipboard": true,
"vim.useCtrlKeys": true,
"vim.handleKeys": {
  "<C-c>": false,
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make VSCodeVim ignore `<D-c>`, not `<C-c>`. `D` is the name of the Cmd key in the settings.

```
"vim.handleKeys": {
  "<D-c>": false,
},
```